# Windows to Evaluate Function on the Fly on VC++ 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

In VC++ 2008, is there a window where I can type in a valid expression ( i.e, a method such as `sqrt(5)` ) and the result will show?

I tried to use the watch windows when I'm doing debugging, but it can only show variable values and do simple computation such as `1+2`; it can't evaluate functions with values.

Anything I miss?

Answer (score 0):

The watch window should work for simple function evaluations. But I believe what you are looking for is called the 'immediate' or 'command' window.

Comment: @Asaaf, not too sure about the immediate windows, but when I type in a perfectly valid expression ( such as `eHalf.Length()`), I got a **expression cannot evaluated** error.

Comment: @Graviton,  is this during runtime? When you evaluate the expression you need to be in the right scope. So unless you are debugging and stepping through each instruction, you are going to need some static reference to the object 'eHalf'.

Comment: @Asaaf, yes, it is during runtime.